# Can we use "it" for referring to people sometimes?

Tags: word-usage

When I'm answering someone asking me about someone else, "Is that him?", can I answer like

> Yes, it's him.

or

> Yes, he is him.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, *it is him* (technically it should be *it is he*, but that can be let slide) is correct, because the *it* in *it is* doesn't refer to an inanimate object being something - *it is* is a special impersonal verb construction that's simply used whenever convenient, and the *it* is not meant to be taken as representative of any person or object.

Examples:

> It is raining outside.
>
> It is he who knocked on the door.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is : Yes, it's him.   Traditional grammar requires that we say: It is he. - since 'he' is the subject of the sentence, but common usage today is : It's him. 'he is him' is wrong.

"It’s me. Can you open the door?"  http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns-personal-i-me-you-him-it-they-etc

Comment: Hi ... many thanks ...Could you give more elaboration why its ( yes , its him ) ...

Comment: Hi...you're welcome. Traditional grammar requires that we say: It is he. - since 'he' is the subject of the sentence, but common usage today is : It's him. 'he is him' is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is : Yes , it's him.

Here are some explanation:

1- Used to refer to a baby:

My baby was sick yesterday?

How is it today?

2- Used with the verb 'be' to emphasize that you are talking about one particular thing, person, group etc and not any other
It's Lawrence you should be talking

3- Used when we ask about unknown person.
For example:
when someone is knocking the door and you ask :
 who is there?
 It's John.

4- Used  to say who is speaking, especially on the telephone

EG: Hello, It's Dallia